# Problem: mat-form-field stay in same line

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I try to include multiple filtering to each column in an angular material table.
But I can't understand why the filter input doesn't move to a new line- under the header?? here is an image -->
[Angular material table with multiple filltering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drMnq.png)

Html:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8" style="text-align:right;" dir="rtl"> 
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="nvOperatorName">
            <th class="header"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                 שם
               <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never">
                    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [formControl]="nameFilter" >
                </mat-form-field>
             </th>
           
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nvOperatorName}} </td>
      
        </ng-container>

        
        <!-- Contact Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="nvContactPerson">
            <th  style="width: 10%;size: 100px;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> שם איש קשר 
                <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never">
                    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [formControl]="ContactNameFilter" >
                </mat-form-field>
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nvContactPerson}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        ...

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

        <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
        <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
            <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  table {
    width: 100%;
    /* overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    min-width: 500px; */
} 
th.mat-header-cell {
    text-align: left;
    max-width: 300px;
}
 
input.matInput{
  direction: rtl;
}

p {
  font-family: Lato;
}


.header {
  padding: 5px;
}

.filter {
  display: block;
}
```

Please help me if u can or another idea for multiple filtering on table...

Answer (score 0):

th tags have a default display value of table-cell meaning that the inner container is not a block level element. The other issue is the mat-form-field has a default width of 180px so the text and the form field will fit into the width of 300px that you gave the table header. To fix this you can either give the mat-form-field a width of 100% or you can wrap the text content of the th tag in a div making it a block level element.

Comment: Hi, thank u for the answer. I tried what u said but didn't work. but I just found out that the mat-sort-header has default Display: flex style... I just change it and it works well!

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with a form its best you create mat-grid-list first

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="60px" dir="rtl">
  <mat-grid-tile>111111</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>22222</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>333333</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile> 4444</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>5555555</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>666</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```